# For some class pair forming disjoint pair via bijection on one of the classes

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set $A$. For every set $B$ can I form set $B'$ such that $|B|=|B'|$ and $A∩B'=\emptyset$?

Is there any hindrances to make this with *proper classes*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course there is a problem with proper classes. Consider the class of all sets, $V$. How can *any* class be disjoint from $V$?

The problem, in a nutshell, is that there is a $\subseteq$-maximal class, but there is no $\subseteq$-maximal set.

Comment: And is it true for sets?

Comment: Yes, because given a set, we can always find a bigger set (and in fact, a *much* bigger set, where we can have this disjoint $B'$).

Comment: Answer #5000! Congrats :)

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I didn't even notice. Thanks. But surely I wrote more, I have just over 500 deleted answers. :)